# Invalid block tag on line 5149: 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? Where am I wrong?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here. I believe I have followed every rule here. Please point out if I missed something. I'd appreciate your help.

```
(% if tot86|floatformat > 0 %)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-end border-start border-dark"><b>Income</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot86|floatformat}}</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot86|floatformat}}</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-end border-start border-dark"><b>AMOUNT PAYABLE</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot90|floatformat}}</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot91|floatformat}}</b></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error in `if` statement you used `(` in place of `{` and `)` in place of `}`. So change `(` to `{` and `)` to `}`

```
{% if tot86|floatformat > 0 %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-end border-start border-dark"><b>Income</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot86|floatformat}}</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot86|floatformat}}</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 text-start fs2 border-bottom border-end border-start border-dark"><b>AMOUNT PAYABLE</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot90|floatformat}}</b></div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center fs2 border-bottom border-end border-dark"><b>{{tot91|floatformat}}</b></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```